# Should I include a product name directory in image URLs for that product for SEO?

Tags: seo, images, image-search

We have created a product page which has product images andare SEO friendly

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="images/my-fancy-product-red-1.jpg" alt="My Fancy product RED" />
    <img src="images/my-fancy-product-blue-2.jpg" alt="My Fancy product BLUE" />
</div>
```

And i have a description box which have illustrative images and graphics and fancy marketing images. Sometimes nice people faces from the stockimages :)

```
<div class="productDescription">
    <h1>My Fancy product is so some</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <div class="coolIcon">
        <img src="images/icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="illustrativeImages">
        <img src="images/fancy-faces.jpg" >
        <img src="images/fancy-faces2.jpg" >
    </div>
</div>
```

So, my question is whether it is reasonable to make images SEO friendly in the description. Like so?

```
<div class="productDescription">
    <h1>My Fancy product is so some</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
    <div class="coolIcon">
        <img src="images/my-fancy-product/icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="illustrativeImages">
        <img src="images/my-fancy-product/fancy-faces.jpg" >
        <img src="images/my-fancy-product/fancy-faces2.jpg" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking about SEO of images within image search or the effect of the images of your products in web search?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:
Yes - it is reasonable to have SEO friendly pictures within your description.

Always! have SEO friendly pictures.

Always use alt="" and always use smart filenames.
Those two are important signals for search engines. Try to use keywords if possible, but dont overdo it.

Comment: Thanks!, Even though the picturs is illustrative and has nothing to do with product it self?

Comment: Yep. No need to keyword stuff, but alt for images is always a nice thing for search engines.